# How can I force NumPy to append a list as an object?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an empty <s>list</s> array declared, as such:

`r = np.array([])`

And I have an operation that adds an array of values to `r` on every loop. Say the first loop adds `[1,2,3]` and the next adds `[4,5,6,7]`. How can I append to the array `r` while forcing the arguments to `append` to be added as *objects* rather than element-wise?

Meaning, I want this after it is finished:

`r = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]])`

where I assume it would be required that `dtype = object`. Or at least that's what I think I want.

If I use

```
r = np.append(r, [1,2,3])
r = np.append(r, [4,5,6,7])
```

I get

`r = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.])`

The only problem is, I need to use this later in a specific way. I need to be able to access the sub-lists individually and do operations on them, but I also, later on, need to be able to access the array as a whole. Normally I would do a `np.ravel` to get this, but I cannot do that when the sub-arrays don't have agreeing lengths (they won't).

Comment: "I have an empty list declared, as such: `r = np.array([])`" - that's an array. It says "array" right there. It's really important to be aware of the differences between lists and arrays, because they're designed completely differently, and using the wrong one can destroy your performance or lead to bugs like the one you're having now.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, I meant array. Clearly I am not confusing lists and arrays because this task is very easy with an ordinary python list.

Comment: You *should be using* an ordinary Python list. You are getting none of the benefits and all of the disadvantages of NumPy by doing things this way. `append`ing to an array is crazy slow, especially if you do it over and over.

Comment: I agree with @user2357112.  Why are you using a numpy array for `r`?  If you want to dynamically append to `r`, and hold sequences of different lengths, an ordinary python list makes much more sense.

Comment: Initialize with : `arr = np.empty(n_iterations,dtype=object)` and then at each iteration set them using the iterator like so : `arr[iter] = [1, 2, 3]`, `arr[iter] = [4, 5, 6, 7]` and so on, where `iter` is the iterator?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension when creating the array:

```
>>> np.array([row for row in [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 6]])
array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 6]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: This would work, but its not very elegant, I would prefer a pure-numpy answer. Also I have to add the sub-arrays one at a time, dynamically

Comment: @jphollowed Numpy wasn't meant for doing such operations. It _won't_ be more efficient than normal lists. Just use normal python lists instead. What is your end-goal? Why do you _need_ an array of list objects?

Comment: `append` is not an elegant in the `numpy` operation.  It is a natural `list` operation, but a contrived `numpy` one.  Build your list `dynamically`, and convert to an array at the end, if at all.